# Linux cron job dont want to run my script

Tags: bash, cron

So i have been trying to make a auto reboot script, most of it works, but when it comes down to my if else statement i dont think it get ran when i run the script via cron job

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -x modded
sleep 2
screen -S modded -X stuff "say restarting in 1 minute"
screen -S modded -X eval "stuff \015"
# [...]
screen -wipe
sleep 2
screen -ls | awk '/\.modded\t/ {print strtonum($1)}' > pid/kill.pid
sleep 1
PIDFile="/home/Minecraft/direwolf20-server1.12/pid/kill.pid"
File=`stat -c %s pid/kill.pid`
if [ $File -lt 1 ];then
    rm pid/kill.pid
    sleep 2
sh ./start
else
    sleep 2
kill -9 $(<"$PIDFile")
    sleep 2
    rm pid/kill.pid
    sleep 2
    screen -wipe
    sleep 2
sh ./start
fi
```

when i run the script my self it works fine

Comment: Usually `sh` != `bash`.

Comment: You can check what's happening in the log file: usually, `/var/log/cron`

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Ensure that the script is marked as executable.
2. When creating the cron entry specify the shell just before the script.
   eg.

   0 */12 * * * /bin/bash /home/foo/script.sh